# Orange add-ons for Mac Os install OK but are not available in the canvas - any clue why?

Tags: orange

I can't get the add-ons to appear on MacOS although the install seems to proceed OK e.g. for Text or Education Modules.

I've added these lines to my profile but still no luck.

export PATH=/Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/jonnylawrence/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/jonnylawrence/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages

Any help appreciated?

Thanks

Comment: Please locate the '$HOME/Library/Logs/Orange Canvas/canvas.log'  file and post its contents. Also please do not modify your profile on the account of Orange. It should not be necessary.